# Convert Linq to SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

What is the equivalent of this **Linq** query in **SQL Server** query?

```
IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = am.Profile.Where(a => articles.Select(b => b.ProfileId).Distinct().Contains(a.ProfileID));
```

where `articles` is:

```
IEnumerable<Article> articles = (from a in am.Article
                                 orderby a.AddedDate descending
                                 select a).ToList();
```

Comment: You can catch the query in SQL Profiler. Most likely it will look weird and human would never write anything like that, but you would get the idea

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I think OP is not using linqToSql because it says Equivalent Linq query in sql server query, and the tags are sql and linq separately

Comment: By the way, assuming this is LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL, if you try this query in LINQPad and click the SQL tab, it will show you what SQL got generated by your code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: probably you're right. It is the first time i use linq. I saw this code in this book:http://www.packtpub.com/asp-net-4-social-networking/book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM Profile P
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Article A
    WHERE A.ProfileId = P.ProfileId
)
```

Apart from that, your linq query is inefficient. Why do you use `Distinct` before `Contains`? It's not necessary to remove duplicates before you use `Contains`.

This is more readable and efficient:

```
IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = am.Profile
    .Where(p => articles.Any(a => a.ProfileID == p.ProfileID));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Profile
WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT ProfileId FROM Article WHERE ProfileId in (SELECT ProfileID FROM  Profile))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this the easiest conversion?

Comment: @Mar_a I'm not sure if it's the most efficient but I'm sure about how easy to understand it. When you select something from a table, just put them after `SELECT` and then filter the records in the `WHERE` clause via the `Key field`. That's the logic I used frequently when working with SQL.

Comment: Why do you use `DISTINCT` in `EXISTS`? The columns won't be selected anyway, so you could also use `EXISTS(SELECT 1...` or `SELECT NULL...` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've just translated it from the `LINQ` (`Contains` method). However I've realized that the solution of `Damien` is shorter. This solution of mine looks like the `LINQ`'s logic. I guess the `ProfileId` is not unique in the `Article` table. Using `DISTINCT` is OK, why not?

Comment: @KingKing: But Exists and Contains doesn't care about dulicates anyway. It is sufficient if one matching ProfileID was found, so removing all the duplicates is just inefficient. According to Damien's approach: i prefer `Exists` since `IN/NOT IN` behave unpredictably with nullable columns. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, it's OK to use `1` instead however using `DISTINCT` is not wrong, it still works, as I said, I've just translated the logic of the `LINQ` into `SQL`, it's not been optimized. Thank you again. However I don't correct the answer, just let it be so.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.*
From [Profile] p
Where p.profileID In (
    Select Distinct ProfileId
    From [Article]
)
```